# Filter but Retain Null Rows

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a melted dataframe that looks like this:

```
# +---+--------+----------+
# | id|  c_type|c_type_val|
# +---+--------+----------+
# |  1|c_type_1|      null|
# |  1|c_type_2|      null|
# |  1|c_type_3|         r|
# |  2|c_type_1|         a|
# |  2|c_type_2|      null|
# |  2|c_type_3|      null|
# |  3|c_type_1|      null|
# |  3|c_type_2|      null|
# |  3|c_type_3|      null|
# +---+--------+----------+
```

I want to condense the rows down to only the rows with a value or for those without a value I'd like to set them to null type and null value like so:

```
# +---+--------+----------+
# | id|  c_type|c_type_val|
# +---+--------+----------+
# |  1|c_type_3|         r|
# |  2|c_type_1|         a|
# |  3|    null|      null|
# +---+--------+----------+
```

Originally I was filtering like this, but it drops the entire row for id=3:

```python
df.filter(df.c_type_val.isNotNull()).show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the `id` column from the original data frame, remove the duplicates and then you can left join it with the filtered result the missing id will have null values for other columns.

```
df.select('id').dropDuplicates().join(
    df.filter(df.c_type_val.isNotNull()), ['id'], how='left'
).show()

+---+--------+----------+
| id|  c_type|c_type_val|
+---+--------+----------+
|  1|c_type_3|         r|
|  3|    null|      null|
|  2|c_type_1|         a|
+---+--------+----------+
```